# Load Test Microsoft Webchat bot

Tags: botframework, load-testing

I am using this [link](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/19/load-testing-a-bot/) as a reference to load test my bot. There are two channels configured - DirectLine & WebChat. I am able to get the access_token and send it in subsequent messages, but the issue is the messages are not flowing as part of single conversation. I am sending the messages like an actual user would send.

example:-

Bot: Are you looking for apparels?

User: Yes

Bot: Men, Kids or Women?

User: Men

etc.
All the user's messages are going a new messages and the BOT code is not able to keep any reference.

I am sending messages to endpoint url - https://xyz/api/messages but when I try to use /v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/{activityId} then it gives resource not found error.

The main objective is to load test the webchat bot by sending messages like an actual user would do. I think there may be configuration missing but let  know if any further information is required.

Answer (score 0):

The API you are using is actually the DirectLine to the bot, not Web Chat. Since you want to emulate the client (Web Chat), the API you actually want to use is detailed in the [REST-API docs for get-activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#get-activities).

`GET /v3/directline/conversations/{conversationId}/activities?watermark={watermark_value}`

Comment: Thanks @Corino for your response. I am using https://github.com/damadei/BotServiceStressToolkit this framework which is able to maintain conversation states.

Comment: Ok. If my response did not help you, please explain what you need and I can try to help.